# How do I back up my Cloudant database to COS?

Tags: database, amazon-s3, couchdb, cloudant

I am trying to back up my Cloudant database to COS (Cloud Object Storage). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Cloudant offers a facility to create backups called [couchbackup](https://github.com/cloudant/couchbackup).
It works by taking a copy of a single Cloudant database. It writes it to a local file by default, but it can be configured to write it to Cloud Object Storage (COS).

This can be done either in two separate operations, first creating the file and then uploading it to COS; or in one operation by streaming the database content directly to COS.

There are examples of how to do both of those [here](https://github.com/cloudant/couchbackup/tree/master/examples).

Remember that IBM COS is fully compatible with AWS S3 so you can store your backups in either of them.